# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'io' in caffe

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, caffe

I am trying to do a gender recognition program, below is the code..

```
import caffe
import os
import numpy as np
import sys
import cv2
import time

#Models root folder
models_path = "./models"

#Loading the mean image
mean_filename=os.path.join(models_path,'./mean.binaryproto')
proto_data = open(mean_filename, "rb").read()
a = caffe.io.caffe_pb2.BlobProto.FromString(proto_data)
mean_image  = caffe.io.blobproto_to_array(a)[0]

#Loading the gender network
gender_net_pretrained=os.path.join(models_path,
'./gender_net.caffemodel')
gender_net_model_file=os.path.join(models_path,
'./deploy_gender.prototxt')
gender_net = caffe.Classifier(gender_net_model_file,     gender_net_pretrained)

#Reshaping mean input image
mean_image = np.transpose(mean_image,(2,1,0))

#Gender labels
gender_list=['Male','Female']

#cv2 Haar Face detector
    face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier(os.path.join
  (models_path,'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'))

 #Getting prediction from live camera
 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

 while True:    
   ret,frame = cap.read()
   if ret is True:
      start_time = time.time()

       frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
       rects = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, 1.3, 5)

       #Finding the largest face
       if len(rects) >= 1:
           rect_area = [rects[i][2]*rects[i][3] for i in xrange(len(rects))]
           rect = rects[np.argmax(rect_area)]
           x,y,w,h = rect
           cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
           roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

           #Resizing the face image
           crop = cv2.resize(roi_color, (256,256))

           #Subtraction from mean file
           #input_image = crop -mean_image
       input_image = rect
           #Getting the prediction
           start_prediction = time.time()
           prediction = gender_net.predict([input_image]) 
           gender = gender_list[prediction[0].argmax()]
           print("Time taken by DeepNet model: {}").format(time.time()-start_prediction)
           print prediction,gender
           cv2.putText(frame,gender,(x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1,(0,255,0),2)

           print("Total Time taken to process: {}").format(time.time()-start_time)
        #Showing output
        cv2.imshow("Gender Detection",frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1) 

#Delete objects
cap.release()
cv2.killAllWindows()
```

When I am running the I am getting an error:

```
a = caffe.io.caffe_pb2.BlobProto.FromString(proto_data)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'io'
```

How Can I solve it. I am using cnn_gender_age_prediction model. I want to make a real time gender recognition program using python and cnn_gender_age model.

Comment: The Error speaks for itself. Try using `dir()` on the module.

Comment: you should have `io.py` file in `$CAFFE_ROOT/python/caffe` folder. If not, then something is wrong with the caffe you got. Try re-install the package.

Comment: @Shai Hi I've seen the folder and I got `io.py`

Comment: can you please type the content of `$CAFFE_ROOT/python/caffe/__init__.py`?

Comment: @SSj.Luffy I did  `dir( )` and I got:
`>>> dir(caffe)
['AdaDeltaSolver', 'AdaGradSolver', 'AdamSolver', 'Classifier', 'Detector', 'Layer', 'NesterovSolver', 'Net', 'NetSpec', 'RMSPropSolver', 'SGDSolver', 'TEST', 'TRAIN', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', '_caffe', 'classifier', 'detector', 'get_solver', 'io', 'layer_type_list', 'layers', 'net_spec', 'params', 'proto', 'pycaffe', 'set_device', 'set_mode_cpu', 'set_mode_gpu', 'set_random_seed', 'to_proto']
>>> `

Comment: @Shai Here's the content of `__init__.py`:


`from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver
from ._caffe import set_mode_cpu, set_mode_gpu, set_device, Layer, get_solver, layer_type_list, set_random_seed
from ._caffe import __version__
from .proto.caffe_pb2 import TRAIN, TEST
from .classifier import Classifier
from .detector import Detector
from . import io
from .net_spec import layers, params, NetSpec, to_proto`

Comment: odd. your `caffe` seems to have `io`. can you do `dir(caffe.io)`?

Comment: Hi @Shai Here's output of  `dir(caffe.io)` :        `>>> import caffe
>>> dir(caffe.io)
['Transformer', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'array_to_blobproto', 'array_to_datum', 'arraylist_to_blobprotovector_str', 'blobproto_to_array', 'blobprotovector_str_to_arraylist', 'caffe_pb2', 'datum_to_array', 'load_image', 'np', 'oversample', 'resize', 'resize_image', 'skimage', 'zoom']
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`io` is a module in `caffe` package. Basically when you type `import caffe`, it will not automatically try to import all modules in `caffe` package including `io`. There are two solutions.

First one: import caffe.io manually

```
import caffe
import caffe.io
```

Second one: update to the latest caffe version, in which you should find a line in `__init__.py` under `python/caffe` directory:

```
from . import io
```

Comment: if you read the comments on the question you will see that the OP has the latest version with the proper import in caffe init